# ifelse returning incorrect values for condition x < very.small.number

Tags: r, if-statement, statistics

I am trying to identify outliers if they are less than a bonferroni corrected p value.  When using ifelse(df$score < bonferroni, 'yes', 'no'), all values are 'yes'.  Which makes NO sense. When I use a p value of 0.05 instead of bonferroni, it works properly.  What is going on here? super annoying.

```
df<- data.frame("cell.id"= c(1:ncol(atac)), "count"=atac$peak_region_fragments, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

lambda <- mean(df$count)
mypoisson$score <- ""
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  message(i)
  df$score[i] <- 1 - ppois(df$count[i], lambda = lambda)
}
bonferroni <- 0.05/ncol(atac)
df$outler <- ifelse(df$score < bonferroni, 'yes', 'no')

bonferroni
[1] 6.52912e-06

head(df)
                   cell.id count             score outler
99_AAACGAAAGCTACGCC-1    1  9618                 1    yes
99_AAACGAAAGGCAGTAC-1    2  5142                 1    yes
99_AAACGAAAGGGCGAAG-1    3  7990                 1    yes
99_AAACGAAAGTCGACCC-1    4  8521                 1    yes
99_AAACGAAAGTTACCAC-1    5  6444                 1    yes
99_AAACGAACAAGCCTTA-1    6 11280 0.964436427969221    yes
```

Yeah... 1 is definitely less than 6.52912e-06... smh

Comment: *"Yeah... 1 is definitely less than 6.52912e-06... smh"* are you **sure**? (Typo in that sentence, I think ;)

Comment: Can can you make your example reproducible? Share some sample data where this doesn't work? We don't have `atac`, so we can't run your code...

Comment: Maybe you could just share your value for `bonfrerroni` and then some sample of `df`. `dput(df[1:10, ])` is a nice way to share a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of your data including all class and structure information. Pick a suitable subset that illustrates the problem.